# using C# route with multiple parameters to call POSTGIS to determine if a point is in a radius

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

Keep Getting Error
"Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): XX000: parse error - invalid geometry"
In postman when i try to run this controller

I tried hard coding in numbers directly into the query and it worked fine
So I assume Im having trouble getting the longitude and latitude from the Route

```cs
[HttpGet("VerifyRegion/{lat}/{longitude}")]
public async Task<Object> VerifyRegion(double lat, double longitude)
{
    string connectionString = "Host=localhost;Username=alex;Password=;Database=PostGISTest";
    await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    
    await using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select ST_DWithin(st_geomfromtext('POINT((@latty) (@longy))', 4326),st_geomfromtext('POINT(54.21 22.54)', 4326), 100);", conn))
    {

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("latty", lat);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("longy", longitude);

        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

        await using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            return Ok(reader.GetBoolean(0));
        }
    };

   

    return Ok();
}
```

SQL:

```sql
select
    ST_DWithin(
        st_geomfromtext(
            'POINT((@latty) (@longy))', 
            4326
        ),
        st_geomfromtext(
            'POINT(54.21 22.54)',
            4326
        ),
        100
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Side note: it is `lon lat`, not `lat lon`.. so probably `POINT((@longy) (@latty))`

Comment: Have you debugged / logged what argument values your action is receiving?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra parenthese around each coordinate. Try removing it.

`st_geomfromtext('POINT(@longy @latty)',4326)`

That being said, it would be stronger to use another method to create the point such as `st_makePoint`. There is no need to cast coordinates to text.

Also, note the coordinate order: longitude first, then latitude.

`st_dwithin` uses the geometries coordinate system, so here you are looking for points within 100 degrees - not meters - of each others.

You can't use `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` as, well, it is a query returning a boolean.